# GNU m4 adds empty lines at top

Tags: markdown, pandoc, m4

I am using GNU m4 to preprocess Pandoc Markdown. I have a m4 script that defines a macro to set text in smallcaps named `gb_Attr`.

```
m4_changequote({{,}})
m4_define({{gb_Attr}}, {{[$1]{.smallcaps}}})
```

and an input Markdown file

```
# Title

Lorem impsum

## Chapter 1

My attribute in gb_Attr(Smallcaps)
```

I call it like the following:

```sh
$ m4 -P script.m4 input.md
```

The macro is expanded correctly but the output begins with two empty lines. How can I prevent those lines?

Comment: Out of curiosity: are you using a preprocessor to save characters, to be more flexible, or because the Markdown keys are placed inconveniently on your keyboard layout?

Comment: @tarleb is just a stub macro. The macro checks if HTML, PDF or EPUB is defined and will expand to different Markdown or specialised HTML. The goal is to have one source for itermediate formats, eBooks and print.

Comment: Thanks, that is cool. We usually suggest [pandoc filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) for this, as that removes dependencies on external programs. They could be a good alternative here. A set of examples is available at https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters.

Comment: @tarleb Thanks for the suggestion! I will have look into it, I am also currently investigating other preprocessors.

Comment: @tarleb Could you point me to an example to a macro with arguments like `{{foo, bar, foobar}}` that would make for example **foo** bold and _bar_ italic and foobar as smallcaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`m4_dnl`](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4-1.4.14/html_node/Dnl.html) (Discard to Next Line) at end of lines!

```
m4_changequote({{,}})m4_dnl
m4_define({{gb_Attr}}, {{[$1]{.smallcaps}}})m4_dnl
```